# Disable saving of captured photos into DCIM folder

Tags: android, camera, directory, photo

I'm taking photos via Intent in my app, photos are saved into my specified folder on SD, but also they are saved into DCIM default camera folder. I do NOT want them twice. How can I disable saving of captured photos into this defalut camera directory?
Thank you in advance.

Here is what I'm using

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
Uri fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: I believe your question was already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078892/stop-saving-photos-using-android-native-camera