# How to change the default folder the SD card saves to?

Tags: android, save, directory, default, sd-card

My application current saves to a folder I've specified `/Pictures/<app_name>/` but it also saves to the default folder `/DCIM/Camera/`. This results in the file being saved to the SD card twice but in different folders. How do I make it so it doesn't save it to both folders, only the folder I specify?

Answer (score 2):

The answer was already get [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8279397/disable-saving-of-captured-photos-into-dcim-folder).

Just go to the original answer ---> [HERE THE SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078892/stop-saving-photos-using-android-native-camera)

I just add the solution to avoid a invalid answer if linked page changes.

Check the following code:

```
private void FillPhotoList() {  
    // initialize the list!    
    GalleryList.clear();    
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME }; 
    for(int i=0;i<projection.length;i++)
        Log.i("InfoLog","projection "+projection[0].toString());
    // intialize the Uri and the Cursor, and the current expected size.    
    Cursor c = null;     
    Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI; 
    Log.i("InfoLog","FillPhoto Uri u "+u.toString());
    // Query the Uri to get the data path.  Only if the Uri is valid.    
    if (u != null)    
    {       
        c = managedQuery(u, projection, null, null, null);    
    }     
    // If we found the cursor and found a record in it (we also have the id).    
    if ((c != null) && (c.moveToFirst()))     
    {       
        do        
        {         
            // Loop each and add to the list.         
            GalleryList.add(c.getString(0)); // adding all the images sotred in the mobile phone(Internal and SD card)

        }            
        while (c.moveToNext());    
    } 
    Log.i(INFOLOG,"gallery size "+ GalleryList.size());
}
```

**and this is where the method is doing all magic**

```
 /** Method will check all the photo is the gallery and delete last captured and move it to the required folder.
 */
public void movingCapturedImageFromDCIMtoMerchandising()
{

    // This is ##### ridiculous.  Some versions of Android save         
    // to the MediaStore as well.  Not sure why!  We don't know what        
    // name Android will give either, so we get to search for this         
    // manually and remove it.           
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE, 
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, 
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, 
            BaseColumns._ID,}; 
    // intialize the Uri and the Cursor, and the current expected size.  

    for(int i=0;i<projection.length;i++)
        Log.i("InfoLog","on activityresult projection "+projection[i]);
    //+" "+projection[1]+" "+projection[2]+" "+projection[3] this will be needed if u remove the for loop
    Cursor c = null;          
    Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;       
    Log.i("InfoLog","on activityresult Uri u "+u.toString());

    if (CurrentFile != null)      
    {                          
        // Query the Uri to get the data path.  Only if the Uri is valid,     
        // and we had a valid size to be searching for.     
        if ((u != null) && (CurrentFile.length() > 0))        
        {              
            //****u is the place from data will come and projection is the specified data what we want
            c = managedQuery(u, projection, null, null, null);      
        }           
        // If we found the cursor and found a record in it (we also have the size). 
        if ((c != null) && (c.moveToFirst()))     
        {             
            do              
            {                
                // Check each area in the gallery we built before.     
                boolean bFound = false;               
                for (String sGallery : GalleryList)                  
                {                      
                    if (sGallery.equalsIgnoreCase(c.getString(1)))  
                    {                      
                        bFound = true;
                        Log.i("InfoLog","c.getString(1) "+c.getString(1));
                        break;                    
                    }                   
                }                   
                // To here we looped the full gallery.                   
                if (!bFound)     //the file which is newly created and it has to be deleted from the gallery              
                {                     
                    // This is the NEW image.  If the size is bigger, copy it.          
                    // Then delete it!                    
                    File f = new File(c.getString(2));




                    // Ensure it's there, check size, and delete!            
                    if ((f.exists()) && (CurrentFile.length() < c.getLong(0)) && (CurrentFile.delete()))     
                    {                       
                        // Finally we can stop the copy.       
                        try                      
                        {                         
                            CurrentFile.createNewFile();     
                            FileChannel source = null;   
                            FileChannel destination = null; 
                            try                           
                            {                         
                                source = new FileInputStream(f).getChannel();
                                destination = new FileOutputStream(CurrentFile).getChannel();  
                                destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
                            } 
                            finally                    
                            {
                                if (source != null)        
                                {   
                                    source.close();  
                                }       
                                if (destination != null)   
                                {   
                                    destination.close(); 
                                }                            
                            }                     
                        }                         
                        catch (IOException e)                 
                        {                            
                            // Could not copy the file over.      
                            ToastMaker.makeToast(this, "Error Occured", 0);   
                        }                      
                    }                   
                    //****deleting the file which is in the gallery                           
                    Log.i(INFOLOG,"imagePreORNext1 "+imagePreORNext);
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    //handler.postDelayed(runnable,300);
                    Log.i(INFOLOG,"imagePreORNext2 "+imagePreORNext);
                    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();       
                    cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, BaseColumns._ID + "=" + c.getString(3), null);

                    break;                                          
                }              
            }            
            while (c.moveToNext());   
        }         
    }       

}
```

Comment: I didn't really get what that method was trying to do. I used this instead and it helped http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563570/double-save-image

Answer (score 1):

For Android Gingerbread version 2.3.3 you can change the cameras default save location. Launch the camera app, click on settings (cog), click on wrench tab, scroll down then select Memory card. Change to Memory card (versus Internal memory).