# Copy pictures from the camera folder Android

Tags: android

I want to copy pictures clicked by the user to the Data folder for an application on the Galaxy Tab. Can someone please help me with the code to move/copy a file from the Media folder to the application data folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey Check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8078892/stop-saving-photos-using-android-native-camera/8079078#8079078)** link where you can also remove the image from DCIM folder where android store default image.